# How do create a stored procedure to delete an item from a table in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: java, sql, stored-procedures, jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am very new to sql, and I am trying to delete a row of person data from a BANK_PERSON table along with its FK constraints. I am using JDBC to declare a callable statement, which takes in a username, then calls a stored procedure in sql and deletes a person from the database.I know the basic process for creating a stored procedure, but I'm not sure how to do it in my case . Here is my BANK_PERSON table and MY BANK_ACCOUNT table with an FK constraint.

```
   CREATE TABLE BANK_PERSON (
   ID_NUMBER INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   FIRSTNAME VARCHAR2(30),
   LASTNAME VARCHAR2(30),
   USERNAME VARCHAR2(30),
   PASS VARCHAR2(30),
   RANK INTEGER
   );


   CREATE TABLE BANK_ACCOUNT (
   ACCOUNT_NUMBER INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   ACCOUNT_BALANCE NUMBER(10,2),
   FOREIGN KEY(ACCOUNT_NUMBER) REFERENCES BANK_PERSON(ID_NUMBER));
```

Comment: What you've got so far for the procedure and where exactly is the problem with that?

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DELETEPERSON is what i have so far, im not sure what goes into it. it should take in a username, so (NAME IN VARCHAR2) as parameters.

Comment: So what is it that is the biggest problem? Creating a PL/SQL stored procedure, or the way to invoke it from Java?

Comment: creating a PL/SQL stored procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I suggest to use `ON DELETE CASCADE` option for your FK which allows you delete all child entries automatically. In other words use following script for creation of `BANK_ACCOUNT` table:

```
CREATE TABLE BANK_ACCOUNT (
   ACCOUNT_NUMBER INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   ACCOUNT_BALANCE NUMBER(10,2),
   FOREIGN KEY(ACCOUNT_NUMBER) REFERENCES A1(ID_NUMBER) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

Then use following script for procedure creation:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE DELETE_PERSON
(USERNAME IN VARCHAR2) AS
BEGIN
  delete from BANK_PERSON where BANK_PERSON.USERNAME like DELETE_PERSON.USERNAME;
END DELETE_PERSON;
```

And finally call of newly created procedure:

```
EXECUTE DELETE_PERSON('Marcus');
```

Hope this is what you would like to get.